# Cloned array gets the same value as original

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array, and want to copy it so I can check if it has changed.

The array looks like this:

```
@table = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

and I copy the values like this:

```
@old_table = @table.clone
```

I have two sorting methods, one that sorts it hortizontaly and the other sorts it vertically.

Everything works fine with the horizontal method but when I use the vertical routine, it changes the value of `@old_table` to the cloned array.

I already checked the object id and it's not the same. I tried with other ways to copy the value too but I get the same result.

Horizontal:

```
currline = 0
4.times do
  @line = @table[currline].clone.reverse
  compare
  sort
  @table[currline] = @line.reverse
  currline += 1
end
```

Vertical:

```
currline = 0
4.times do
  @line = [@table[0][currline],@table[1][currline],@table[2][currline],@table[3][currline]].reverse
  compare
  sort
  @line.reverse!
  @table[0][currline] = @line[0]
  @table[1][currline] = @line[1]
  @table[2][currline] = @line[2]
  @table[3][currline] = @line[3]
  currline += 1
end
```

Here's a link to the whole code: http://pastebin.com/1xzLx5ib

I need help to figure out why the vertical method changes the value of `@old_table` to the original when it shouldn't.

Comment: Your first four words are somehwat wrong:  "I have an array"  You actually have 5 arrays, and you only cloned one of them.  Ruby has no built-in support for 2-dimensional arrays, so you just have to put arrays inside arrays.

Comment: You need `@old_table = @table.map(&:clone)`. In this case you could use either `clone` or `dup`.

Comment: ...or (in this case): `@old_table = @table.map {|a| [*a]}` or `@old_table = @table.transpose.transpose`.

Comment: Changed it to @old_table = @table.map{|i|i.clone} after Matt posted the answear. Might seem like a dumb question but what does the [*a] part mean in map {|a| [*a]}?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all.  The "splat" operator converts an array to its individual elements. For example: `[*[1,2,3]] = [1,2,3]`.  Another example, showing it also works with ranges: `[*[1,2], *3..5, 'hi'] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "hi"]`.  Note `a = [1,2]; a.object_id #=> 70182215447260; b = [*a] #=> [1,2]; b.object_id #=> 70182215410040; a = [3]; b #=> [1,2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the outer array is cloned, but not the 4 inner arrays.

```
@table = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
@old_table = @table.clone
@old_table.object_id
# => 70198498995020 
@table.object_id
# => 70198498975440 (So far so good)

@old_table[0].object_id
# => 70198498975520 
@table[0].object_id
# => 70198498975520 (Same row id!)
```

One simple way to fix this is to serialize and unserialize the array:

```
@old_table = Marshal.load Marshal.dump(@table)
```

Comment: [`Marshal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Marshal.html) would be a better choice than JSON in the general case.

Comment: @muistooshort (or Matt), please elaborate JSON vs Marshal for a deep copy.

Comment: Thank you, did test the object id for strings in an array so i thought it was the same for arrays.

Comment: @CarySwoveland JSON only supports a limited set of datatypes. If you're only dealing with numbers, strings, arrays, and hashes then JSON will work out okay but if you have "real" objects then you won't get the same thing out of JSON that you put into it.